# iTunes Connect - re-add app to appstore as new release

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

what happens if I remove my app from tunes connect and re-add it again to get listed again in the daily releases? does apple checks any checksumor something?
(I am asking becaus I missed to get into this list because of changing my release date after approval and didn't know that then the app is missing the release-list)

Comment: This question doesn't belong to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reupload an app with the same bundle version.

Just change your Bundle version (in info.plist) from 1.0 to 1.0.1

Comment: And add a release description like "minor bug fix"

Comment: but then the app doesn't appear in the "new apps of the day" list again, right?